# How can I avoid redundant conditionals in client-side validation?

Tags: javascript, json

I have code which uses many conditional statements and has become complicated. I'm searching for a more efficient way to validate input.

My code receives the result of server-side validation as JSON. For each of many inputs, if the input's value is invalid, a corresponding `false` is returned by the server. Conditional statements modify the UI appropriately. Here's a sample:

```
else if((data.address===false)&&(data.city===false)&&(data.municipality===false))
{
    $('#adrserror').html('You have to put an address, city and municiplaity.'); 
    $('label.error').hide();
    $('.openpaddress').find('input').prop('readonly', false);
}
else if((data.address===false)&&(data.city===false))
{
    $('#adrserror').html('You have to fill the address and the city fields.'); 
    $('label.error').hide();  
    $('.openpaddress').find('#municipality').prop('readonly', true).css('border', '0px');   
}
else if((data.city===false)&&(data.municipality===false))
    ...
```

The HTML contains just three input elements (for address, city, and municipality) with accompanying labels.

Comment: one cute trick is to make a lookup table keyed with combinations of the  values or derivatives of the values. for example, var key=[data.address,data.city, data.municipality].join("|");. then you have an object of methods with keys like "false|true|false" or "false|false|true". you can instantly find and fire the right method using objMethods[key](); no IFs and or butts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var missing = [];
var fields = ['address', 'city', 'municipality'];
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    var f = fields[i];
    if (data[f] === false) {
        missing.push(f);
    }
}
if (missing.length > 0) {
    $('#adrserror').text('Please fill in fields: ' + missing.join(', '));
}
```

Comment: your code does exactly what I want, thanks for the help. Furthermore, I do not agree with the negative vote I got for my question. I did tried  to find a solution to my problem before posting.I just do not know loops good enough...

Comment: I want to add something in my question. Before that I want to stress that I tried really hard to find a solution to the problem I am about to describe. Suppose we have a 4th input element, that is optional. It is the URL. How am i going to integrate that logic in the code above,furthermore the displayed message must be differente now: "You have not entered a correct URL". So we might have a case where the user opts to fill a url field also. This must be combined with the above code somehow.

Comment: If it's optional, the above code doesn't need to do anything with it, it's only checking for required fields. If you want to check it for valid syntax, do that in addition to the above code. Then you can append the error message to the text of the error DIV.